# Ubuntu showing Memory 1,4GiB, but laptop had 6

Tags: ram

Acer Aspire V5-122P-0408
I had 2 x 2gb ram and replaced 1 for a 4Gb ram.
In the bios it recognizes 6GB but Ubuntu only sees the 2Gb ram. (usable memory 1,4GiB)
It´s all 64bit and I tried reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 and upgraded to 17.10 but still the same.

Comment: What does it show if you remove the 2Gb?

Comment: @CarlH One of the modules is soldered. Only 1*2GB can be replaced in that model.